# How to get a particular variable from another script

Tags: php

Can I fetch any variable (eg: username) from another script? Suppose there is a id which is in another table and I want to use as the 'id' field as  foreign key in the new table. So how can I fetch it?

```
<?php 
$submit=$_POST['submit'];
include_once('connection.php');
include_once('Home.php');
//Form Data 
$id=mysql_query("SELECT id from users WHERE username='$username' "); 
$pickup=strip_tags($_POST['pickup']);
$drop=strip_tags($_POST['drop']);
$time=strip_tags($_POST['time']);
$date=date("Y-m-d");
//$orderid =strip_tags($_POST['orderid']);
if($submit)
{ //check for existance 
    if($pickup && $drop && $time) 
    { 
        $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ambu_book VALUES ('','$pickup','$drop','$time','$date','')");
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Please fill in all fields ! <p>";
    }
}?>
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear. Please give more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to fetch $username from another script which is not declared in my current one . How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a variable from another php script if you do `require()` or `include` the script in the invocking script. But for how you did you wrote your question it seems you have an issue related to sql rather than php, i think.

Comment: I have used this code but till $id is not fetching up

Comment: @AnirbanGhosh, you are bad clearing things. Also, make sure that your database has the id in there